# JointIterable: iterates over all elements of a list of collections

Tags: java, iterator, collections, iteration

I have this small utility class that allows me to iterate over a series of collections. Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

**JointIterable.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public final class JointIterable<E> implements Iterable<E> {

    /**
     * Holds the list of iterable objects.
     */
    private final List<Iterator<E>> iterators;

    /**
     * Constructs a new joint iterable. 
     * 
     * @param iterables the iterable object to iterate.
     */
    public JointIterable(Iterable<E>... iterables) {
        if (iterables == null) {
            this.iterators = new ArrayList<>(0);
        } else {
            this.iterators = new ArrayList<>(iterables.length);

            for (Iterable<E> iterable : iterables) {
                if (iterable != null) {
                    this.iterators.add(iterable.iterator());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new JointIterator();
    }

    private final class JointIterator implements Iterator<E> {

        private int currentIteratorIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            while (currentIteratorIndex < iterators.size() &&
                    !iterators.get(currentIteratorIndex).hasNext()) {
                currentIteratorIndex++;
            }

            return currentIteratorIndex < iterators.size();
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Nothing left for iteration.");
            }

            return iterators.get(currentIteratorIndex).next();
        }
    }
}
```

**JointIterableDemo.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public final class JointIterableDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<String> yeahs1 = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
        Set<String> yeahs2 = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> yeahs3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("three", 
                                                           "four",
                                                           "five"));
        Set<String> yeahs4 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("six"));

        for (String yeah : new JointIterable<String>(yeahs1,
                                                     null,
                                                     yeahs2,
                                                     yeahs3,
                                                     yeahs4)) {
            System.out.println(yeah);
        }
    }
}
```

**JointIterableTest.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public final class JointIterableTest {

    private Iterable<String> jointIterable;

    @Test
    public void testNullIterableList() {
        jointIterable = new JointIterable<String>(null);    
        assertFalse(jointIterable.iterator().hasNext());
    }

    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testNullIterableListThrowsOnNext() {
        new JointIterable<String>(null).iterator().next();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyIterableList() {
        jointIterable = new JointIterable<String>();
        assertFalse(jointIterable.iterator().hasNext());
    }

    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testEmptyIterableListThrowsOnNext() {
        new JointIterable<String>().iterator().next();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOmitsNullIterable() {
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("one");
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("two", "three");
        jointIterable = new JointIterable<String>(null, 
                                                  list1, 
                                                  null, 
                                                  null, 
                                                  list2, 
                                                  null);

        assertTrue(jointIterable.iterator().hasNext());
        assertEquals("one", jointIterable.iterator().next());

        assertTrue(jointIterable.iterator().hasNext());
        assertEquals("two", jointIterable.iterator().next());

        assertTrue(jointIterable.iterator().hasNext());
        assertEquals("three", jointIterable.iterator().next());

        assertFalse(jointIterable.iterator().hasNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The easy stuff

Let's start with the easy stuff first:

- Instead of creating a `new ArrayList<>(0)`, it's better to use `Collections.emptyList()` when possible. This will avoid unnecessary object creation.
- Similarly, if there are no (more) iterators to iterate, then instead of creating a `new JointIterator()`, it would be better to use `Collections.emptyIterator()`.
- Since you already filter out `null` iterators at the time of construction, I think it will also make sense to filter out empty iterators.

Based on the above, I would rewrite the constructor and `iterator()` like this:

```
  @SafeVarargs
  public JointIterable(Iterable<E>... iterables) {
    if (iterables == null) {
      this.iterators = Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
      this.iterators = Stream.of(iterables)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .map(Iterable::iterator)
          .filter(Iterator::hasNext)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
  }

  @Override
  @Nonnull
  public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    List<Iterator<E>> nonEmptyIterators = iterators.stream()
        .filter(Iterator::hasNext)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return nonEmptyIterators.isEmpty()
        ? Collections.emptyIterator()
        : new JointIterator(nonEmptyIterators.iterator());
  }
```

#### Iterable and iterator behavior

Most iterables I know of can be iterated on multiple times.
Normally if I'm given an `Iterable<E>`,
I can call `.iterator()` on it multiple times and get the same values.
The current implementation doesn't behave like that,
once iterated over,
it is consumed, further iterations will be empty.
As I don't normally see this pattern,
it might be surprising to others too.

#### Smelly `hasNext`

I think it's a *code smell* that `hasNext` mutates the state of `JointIterator`.
It would be better to rework in a way that only `next` would change internal state.

Consider this alternative implementation of `JointIterator`:

```
  private final class JointIterator implements Iterator<E> {

    private final Iterator<Iterator<E>> iterators;
    private Iterator<E> iterator;

    private JointIterator(Iterator<Iterator<E>> nonEmptyIterators) {
      this.iterators = nonEmptyIterators;
      iterator = this.iterators.next();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
      E value = iterator.next();
      if (!iterator.hasNext() && iterators.hasNext()) {
        iterator = iterators.next();
      }
      return value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I thought about a follow-up question, but that would be pretty much code plagiarism. What do you think on this matter?

Comment: @coderodde I think it's not plagiarism when you give credit. So feel free to go ahead.